# Updating displayed data on mouse enter

Tags: reactjs

I would like to update text which is displayed inside a `<div>` element. I would love to do it when the cursor enters the `<div>` element.

Basically I'm fetching some data from the API and I display only one parameter (`name`). If a user enters the `<div>` with the name displayed I would like to show some details, i.e. `description` and `price`.

This is my code which I tried to complete my task.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import requestOptionsGet from "../utilities/requestOptions";
import validateResponse from "../utilities/validators";


const Warehouse = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [texts, setTexts] = useState([]);

    const getItems = async () => {
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/items/"
        return await fetch(url, requestOptionsGet)
            .then((response) => validateResponse(response, url))
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setItems(data))
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTexts(items.map((item) => (
            {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                description: item.description,
                price: item.price,
                currentDisplay: <h2>{item.name}</h2>,
            })
        ))
    }, [items]);

    const displayName = (data) => {
      console.log(
          "displayName"
      );
    };

    const displayDetails = (data) => {
        const itemID = parseInt(data.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-item"));
        const displayInfo = texts.find(text => text.id === itemID);

        displayInfo.currentDisplay = <p>{displayInfo.description}</p>

        setTexts(texts);

        console.log(texts);

        console.log(
            "displayDetails"
        );

        return(
            displayInfo.currentDisplay
        );
    };

    return(
          <div className="container">
              <h1>Your warehouse.</h1>
              <h2>All your items are listed here.</h2>
              <hr />
              {texts.map((text) => (
                  <button className="container-for-single-item" id={text.id} key={text.id}
                          onMouseEnter={displayDetails} onMouseLeave={displayName} data-item={text.id}>
                      {text.currentDisplay}
                  </button>
             ))}
          </div>
    );
}

export default Warehouse;
```

The functions work (everything is displayed in the console as it should be) and even the `texts` change. However the paragraph does not appear. How can I fix my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never modify state directly

```
const newTexts = texts.map(text => text.id === itemID ? { ...text, currentDisplay: <p>{text.description}</p> } : text);
setTexts(newTexts);
```